# UIPath Tibco EMS Integration

Tags: tibco, uipath

We are trying to send a message to the Tibco EMS queue from the UiPath Tool.
Is it possible to this via the paelltes/activities or we need to write some custom Code.
Please let me know if anyone is aware.

Answer (score 0):

If UIPath support JMS connectivity you should be able to get this to work by copying TIBCO EMS client Jar files to the UIpath environment (note that you should have an EMS client licence to do that).